# Trying to open a file in C++, but the file cannot be found

Tags: clion

I have an algorithm in **C++** (*main.cpp*) and I use **CLion** to compile and run it. Algorithm would read strings from text file, but there is a mistake:

*Could not open data.txt* (file exists and placed in one folder with *main.cpp*)

How can I fix it and make this file "visible" to CLion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `fopen` or something similar and just passing `"data.txt"`, it is assumed that that file is in the current working directory of the running program (the one you just compiled).

So, either

1. Give a full path instead, like `fopen("/full/path/to/data.txt")`, where you use the actual full path
2. (not preferable), Move data.txt to the directory where CLion runs its compiled programs from.

(for #2, here's a hacky way to get that directory)

```
char buf[1024]; // hack, but fine for this
printf("%s\n", getcwd(buf, 1024));
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Run/Edit configurations...
2. Select your application (on the lefthandside of the window)
3. Specify Working directory
4. Apply

Now you can `fopen` relatively from working directory.

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to solve this problem.

@Lou Franco's solution may affect the project structure. For example, if I deploy code on a server, I should move the resource file to specific directory.

What I do is **modify the CmakeLists.txt**, on Windows, using

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "D:\\science\\code\\English-Prediction")
```

*CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY* is a CMake variable, it assigns the work directory of CLion work directory.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` CMakeLists variables, I do the following. In the root directory of my project, I create a directory, e.g., `out`. Then, in my `CMakeLists.txt` I set the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to that directory:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/out)
```

Note, that must come before you have

```
add_executable(YourProject ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I might also add that instead of using `fopen()` I would keep it more object-oriented by using `std::ifstream`:

```
std::ifstream inFile("data.txt");
// check if it opened without issue...
if (!inFile) {
    processError(); // a user-defined function to deal with the issue
} else {
    // All is good, carry on...
    // and when you're done don't forget 
    inFile.close();
}
```